# No UIButton Edge option in Xcode 8

Tags: uibutton, xcode8, ios10

I'm using Xcode 8. I'm trying to add a `UIButton` with `Image` on left side and `Title` right side. I would like to maintain distance between `Image` and `Title` of the `UIButton` in `Storyboard`. I can't see `Edge` option here. Any help here is much appreciated.

Answer (score 24):

Using **Storyboard**

> Environment : XCode 8

[image: Xcode8]

*Note : In Xcode 8 you will find the `Edge` option in Size inspector which named as Content Insets, Title Insets and Image Insets.*

> Environment : XCode 7

[image: Xcode7]

Using **Code**.

> Swift 3

```
myButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(_ top: CGFloat, _ left: CGFloat, _ bottom: CGFloat, _ right: CGFloat);
myButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(_ top: CGFloat, _ left: CGFloat, _ bottom: CGFloat, _ right: CGFloat);
```

> Objective C

```
[myButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(CGFloat top, CGFloat left, CGFloat bottom, CGFloat right)];
[myButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(CGFloat top, CGFloat left, CGFloat bottom, CGFloat right)];
```

Answer (score 9):

**Xcode 8 StoryBoard:**

First set the title and image to the button, and go to the size inspector and set title insets and image insets, it will align the content to desired location. In your case set title inset left and image insets right.

[image]

**Programatically:**

```
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right);
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right);
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Xcode 7 StoryBoard:**

[image]
[image]

Xcode 7 Edge option has been moved from Attribute inspector to Size inspector section in Xcode 8, and named as Content insets, Title insets and Image insets.

Comment: I don't know this change in Xcode 8. If I want to add image at the right of the button with title left side, how to do this ? As per you earlier answer it seems I have to hard code the value of the image 'right' option to some 300/500 pixels. But I remember earlier we have option to select image and set its alignment to right side of the button. Now I can't see that here. Any help ? This hard coded values doesn't work on both orientations.

Comment: What your asking for has been changed like above in Xcode8. In Xcode7, you can set the edge left/right by selecting title or image. from Xcode8, same has been renamed and moved to size inspector section ie. Title insets and image insets. If you want, you can hard code or you can dynamically add spacing to button by using button size.

Comment: This options are not helping me, I will find out my solution, Thank you

Comment: Your question clearly states that Edge option is missing to set the left/right spacing to the button, the answer given was the alternative of edge option in Xcode8. This is the exact edge option in Xcode8. i don't know why it is not helpful to you. Please explain and If you have any further question regarding this please update the question. Thank you.